# Angular 5 ngModel doesn't update value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, ngmodel

I have the following component:

```
export class ModuleComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    dropzoneConf;
    fileService = environment.getFileUrl;

    constructor(
        private moduleComponentService: ModuleComponentService) {
    }

    @Input()
    selectedComponent: ModuleComponent;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.setDropZoneConfig();
    }    
}
```

And in that I have the following HTML:

```
<h3 class="m-portlet__head-text m--font-success">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" [ngModel]="selectedComponent.title" />
</h3>
```

and the way I add the component in my HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-x1-12" *ngIf="selectedComponent != null">
   <app-module-component [selectedComponent]="selectedComponent"></app-module-component>
</div>
```

When I type something into the input field it doesn't update the `selectedComponent.title` variable

What might be going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the two way binding

```
 [(ngModel)]="selectedComponent.title"
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use two-way data binding

> [(ngModel)]

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedComponent.title" />
```

> and make sure to import forms module in **app.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to use two way data binding with [(ngModel)]

```
<h3 class="m-portlet__head-text m--font-success">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedComponent.title" />
</h3>
```

[You should read the part about two way data binding on Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngmodel---two-way-binding-to-form-elements-with-ngmodel)

If you want to use **[ngModel]** only, you could but you have to catch changes with **(ngModelChange)**

```
<h3 class="m-portlet__head-text m--font-success">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" [ngModel]="selectedComponent.title" (ngModelChanges)="setTitle($event)" />
</h3>
```

You could improve it with forms, just ask me for any questions about that